# Use IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary with library expecting a regular Python dictionary

Tags: python, windows, ironpython, pytest

I'm trying to use PyTest with IronPython but one module in Py is expecting a pure Python dictionary but is getting an a IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary. Is there a way to avoid the error below? I could hypothetically modify the py_apipkg.py module.

```
>>> import pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pytest.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\_pytest\core.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\py\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\py\_apipkg.py", line 33, in initpkg
SystemError: Unsupported param dictionary type: IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary
```

Comment: `IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary` *is* IronPython's builtin dict type. Something odd is going on. Can you file an issue (https://ironpython.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create)?

Answer (score 0):

Use unittest instead of PyTest

```
use unittest
```

Then make sure that your test case class inherits from unittest.TestCase

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def Test1(self):
        t = MyClass()
        self.AssertEquals(1, t.One, 'Example')
```